# Rebooted and php mail script is failing again on OSX

Tags: php, sendmail

I was having trouble getting my mail php mail script to work yesterday but I finally got it going.  Now I just turned my computer back on after a shutdown and its not working again.  I am getting this message in my mail.log:

Oct  1 11:22:26 alexander-repennings-imac postfix/sendmail[352]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specifie\
d on the command line or via the -t option
Oct  1 11:22:26 alexander-repennings-imac postfix/master[354]: daemon started -- version 2.4.3, configuratio\
n /etc/postfix
Oct  1 11:23:26 alexander-repennings-imac postfix/master[354]: master exit time has arrived

The PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $to = "MichaelMinerva2012@gmail.com"; 
  $subject = "Competition Submission";
  $name_field = $_POST['name'];
  $email_field = $_POST['email'];

  $value_field = $_POST['sendvalue'];


  $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n  Value: $value_field\n";


  if(mail($to, $subject, $body))
      echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
  else
      echo "failure";

      } else {
           echo "blarg!";
      }
    ?>
```

Which is once again echoing failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the sendmail_path value isn't set in php.ini. Open it to see if the following line is uncommented*

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Worked for me once.

*assuming you are running on Unix system

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to get PHP work with the mail command long ago. Usually it worked, but on hosted systems it always seemed to be an issue. I switched to SwiftMailer, which is a PHP emailing tool. You can login to just about any host, including gmail, and send emails from there.